# Meaning of were it to

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "**were it to**" used in the following sentence?

> The developing storm, **were it to become** a cyclone on Tuesday, will
> be called NIVAR, said Mr. Mohapatra. It currently hovers about 520 km
> south-southeast of Puducherry and 560 km south-southeast of Chennai.

Does it mean **if it becomes**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. "The developing storm, were it to become a cyclone on Tuesday, will be called NIVAR" means the same as " If the developing storm becomes a cyclone on Tuesday, it will be called NIVAR"

From Google definitions for 'were': Used to hypothesize about something that might happen.

> Example: "if I were to lose"

Comment: Why would the author have chosen to use this form if "if" is a much more common form to introduce a possibility? Is there a reason to prefer one over the other in the given context?

Comment: It seems(in my head) like it's used when you're discussing a point in the future where you would be looking back on the condition/possibility. Like in this example they are talking about the point in the future where the naming is occurring but also referring back to the condition. It's a hard one to think about the difference and I can't think of a situation where you would be wrong or sound strange by choosing the simpler if form